# Package inputenc - Unicode character not set up for use with LaTeX - knitting to pdf wih xelatex fails in RStuio

Tags: r, unicode, r-markdown, pdflatex, xelatex

I have an exotic problem with RMarkdown and knitting a pdf. Knitting html and word documents works fine. I'm running RStudio Version 1.2.5033 and TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019 Gentoo Linux).

I have a file, which among other things recodes user input data. Some user has (God knows how) entered '2⁸' into the data file, and I need to recode this to 2. There are several other SO questions on this topic - for example [Package inputenc Error & Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35715986/package-inputenc-error-error-pandoc-document-conversion-failed-with-error-43?rq=1) and [Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8 in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794157/package-inputenc-error-unicode-char-u8-in-rstudio).

The standard advice, to deal with the limits of pdflatex's implementation of Unicode, is to use xelatex, which I'm doing, but it still does not work.

So, first effort - using pdflatex - crashes when knitting a pdf with the message

```
'! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ⁸ (U+2078) (inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.'
```

Replacing this with xelatex by

```
output: pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
```

will produce a pdf, but all the ⁸ are blank. This is not the case when knitting to HTML or Word, and in fact the pdf produced by saving the Word document as a pdf in LibreOffice looks fine, with all the 2⁸ correctly rendered.

The output is 
[output of running R deleted]

```
/usr/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS LatexTest.utf8.md --to latex 
--from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output LatexTest.tex
--self-contained --highlight-style tango --latex-engine xelatex --variable graphics
--variable 'geometry:margin=1in' --include-in-header
/tmp/RtmpdLZWBq/rmarkdown-str18dc3dcea436.html 

output file: LatexTest.knit.md


Output created: LatexTest.pdf
Warning message:
Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 129.
Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 133.
Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 133.
Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 139.
Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 143.
Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 143.
Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 149.
Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 154.
Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 154.
Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 160.
Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 164.
Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 164.
```

The test file, which produces these errors is attached. When running this it claims to be using the xelatex engine.

````
---
title: "Latex test"
author: "Anthony Staines"
date: "13/04/2020"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
  html_document: default
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

cat('2⁸')
print('2⁸')

Test = ('2⁸')
cat(Test)
print(Test)

## 2⁸
 2⁸
 2⁸
 2⁸
````

Any suggestions? The Latex advice is to add the offending character to the Latex file, which would suit me fine, but I don't know how to give arbitrary Latex commands in Markdown or YAML. In any event, I wonder if this is a bug. It should just work with xelatex.

Comment: I think the issue in xelatex is that the font has no glyph for that character, but I don't know how to find a font that does.  I'd ask on tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Good suggestion I'll try that in a day or two. I've already dealt with this manually, so it's not urgent. Thanks!

Comment: I've just bumped into this problem. Could you add an answer or comment as to how you managed this manually?  Before I start experimenting to find a resolution.